# While opening visual studio code a black screen appear

Tags: visual-studio-code

A fully black screen,the window pannnel is fully black and while browse this issue --disable-gpu bt it doesn't work.
Can anybody answer

Answer (score 0):

It will work by changing the compatibility on vs code
Right click on visual studio ->preference->compatibility-> Run this program in compatibility mode

Thus the problem can be resolved
OR on your command prompt type
code --disable-gpu

Answer (score 0):

It will work by changing the compatibility on vs code Right click on visual studio ->preference->compatibility-> Run this program in compatibility mode

Thus the problem can be resolved OR on your command prompt type code --disable-gpu

Tried the above steps issue is not resolved. Still getting Black Screen